# How to refresh the app database silently?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my code logic I have 30 min time expiration condition. When the current time is equal to time activated + 30 min, the activation will get expired. Internally in the SQLite, I need to update IsActive flag = 0.

How to refresh the app database silently?

Comment: You will need to do this with a background service in each respective OS.

Comment: is it on an event ?

Comment: When does the expiration condition is checked? At launch, at resume or somewhere else? If you check and the condition is hit fire an sql query and set the flag as you need. What exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t even need to update a flag. You just need a date field in your database.

Assuming you are using an ORM like [sqlite-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) or similar:

```
YourEntity.ActivationDate = DateTime.Now;
// save your entity
```

Later on:

```
var entity = // get the entity from database
var isActivated = DateTime.Now < entity.ActivationDate.AddMinutes(30);
```

The very same code that checks for activation could update the flag:

```
var entity = // get the entity from database
if(entity.IsActive && DateTime.Now > entity.ActivationDate.AddMinutes(30))
{
    entity.IsActive = false;
    // save entity to db table
}
```

This way you avoid implementing background services.

Comment: i implemented the same logic of mentioning the date time.now >= activation date time.. it works very well .. thanks